# Modifying all arrays in a multi array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to "paint" some grid with a rectangle area. But when I try to modify just one row the array modifies all of them. I tried to initialize the array in several ways, but the problem seems to be when I try to modify it, not the Array object.

```js
var multiArray = Array(8).fill(Array(8).fill(false));

// Fill square 3x1 at (2, 4)
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
    multiArray[2 + i][4 + j] = true;
  }
}

document.getElementById("content").innerHTML =
  multiArray.map(a => a.map(e => e ? 'X' : '0').join(''))
    .join('<br />');
```

```html
<div id="content" />
```

At this point instead of providing a solution for this case I only want to understand why is that happening. What's the problem with `[][]` expression.

I'm trying this in Chrome version 51.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Array(8).fill(Array(8).fill(false))` only creates two arrays, one of which contains eight references to the other. This is more obvious if you break it into two lines - the following is equivalent:

```
var tempArray = Array(8).fill(false);
var multiArray = Array(8).fill(tempArray);
```

So that's not what you want. Try something like this instead:

```
var multiArray = Array(8).fill(0).map(_=>Array(8).fill(false));
```

I've filled the first array with zeros just as placeholders so that `.map()` will visit all of those elements, then for each element my little map callback returns a *new* array filled with `false`.

In context:

```js
var multiArray = Array(8).fill(0).map(_=>Array(8).fill(false));

// fill square 3x1 at (2, 4)
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
    multiArray[2 + i][4 + j] = true;
  }
}

document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = 
  multiArray.map(a => a.map(e => e ? 'X' : '0').join(''))
  .join('<br />');
```

```html
<div id="content" />
```

Comment: Great, I tried to put the map also without the zeros fill, but Array() messed up with me. Thanks a lot ;)

Answer (score 0):

Creating an N dimension array is a little tricky since arrays are of reference types. I had done something as follows previously. The `arrayND` function takes sizes of each dimension as arguments and the last argument is the initializing value. I hope it helps.

```js
Array.prototype.clone = function(){
  return this.map(e => Array.isArray(e) ? e.clone() : e);
};
function arrayND(...n){
  return n.reduceRight((p,c) => c = (new Array(c)).fill().map(e => Array.isArray(p) ? p.clone() : p ));
}
var arrND = arrayND(8,8,false);
console.log(arrND);
```